# Is there any resource where a Python 2.7 dev can get up to speed with Python 3.3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-3.3

I was using python 2.7 for the last few years. I had a lot of libraries I used that weren't yet compatible with Python 3 and my general feeling was that it wasn't settled enough for me.

Lately I've heard so many people talking about how good Python 3.3 is that I realized maybe I lagged behind for too long.

So, what are the main resources for someone like me, who stayed in 2.7 until now, to get up to speed with the syntax differences, new standard library features and general questions of idiomatic code?

Edit:

As suggested by @PhilH, it would be nice to have a few comments on the main advantages of using python 3.3 over 2.7 and tips on features python 3.3 that can make a difference in readability, performance, etc.

Comment: http://getpython3.com/diveintopython3/

Comment: I suggest you alter this question to include what people think makes a difference to coding in 3.x vs 2.x, as the rest of the answers will just be links.

Comment: Also, note that you can import things via `import x from __future__` to use in existing 2.x scripts.

Comment: http://python3porting.com/, particularily http://python3porting.com/differences.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

THe "What's New" documents for each 3.x release is the best place. For example, version 3.3 was just released, the [What's New](http://docs.python.org/3.3/whatsnew/3.3.html) page has a good description of... what's new. There is another describing 3.x in general. Google will find it for you.

Comment: I'd read those "What's New" pages sequentially: [3.0](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html), [3.1](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.1.html), [3.2](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.2.html), [3.3](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html).

Answer (score 0):

[Dive Into Python 3](http://getpython3.com/diveintopython3/) Is one place to start, it's also free.
Also, Mark Lutz's all-time classic [Learning Python, 4th edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596158068) covers differences between 2 and 3 explicitly wherever they occur.